# Elasticsearch replace whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to find a tokenizer in elasticsearch that would replace all the whitespaces with a blank and convert multiple words into a single word.

For example: Abd al Qadir  ===> Abdalqadir

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve that would be to create a custom filter using the `pattern_replace` filter, and create a custom analyzer with that filter and the `lowercase` one.

Here's an example of how the configuration would look like:

```
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "whitespace_remove": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": " ",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "whitespace_remove"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```